# data pass into Input text value to display data on another input texts

Tags: javascript

I a'm trying to pass a value into input text and click search to output other values in other input texts

Input forms to pass data and to display  data searched

```
      <input type="text" name="" id="inputData" value="" placeholder="">
      <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">search</button><br><br>

      <input type="text" name="" id="genes" ><br>
      <input type="text" name="" id="generation"><br>
      <input type="text" name="" id="date"><br>
      <p id="text"></p>
```

Script to execute the functions

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function myFunction(){
          if (document.getElementById("inputData").value == 1) {
                var  gs = das356572gdsjhds878ilko20992;
                var gn = 12;
                var dt = 12/12/2018;
                document.getElementById("genes").value =  +gs;
                document.getElementById("generation").value =  +gn;
                document.getElementById("date").value =  +dt;
                } 
                       }
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`das356572gdsjhds878ilko20992` and `12/12/2018` are strings.

Therefore change it to:

```
var  gs = "das356572gdsjhds878ilko20992";
var dt = "12/12/2018";
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're trying to do is check the inputData-field on searchbutton-clicked. And if the inputField's value == 1 then set the other inputs to the following variables.

```
var gs = das356572gdsjhds878ilko20992;
var gn = 12;
var dt = 12/12/2018;
```

The only problem I see is that your variables are of an invalid type, you have to put quotes (' or ") around them, otherwise they will be interpreted as variables and mathematical operations, and since the variable das356572gdsjhds878ilko20992 doesn't exist it will return an error.

Fix:

```
var gs = 'das356572gdsjhds878ilko20992';
var gn = 12;
var dt = '12/12/2018'; // If you want it to be a date, otherwise if you just want to divide 12 by 12 by 2018 then it's okay as var dt = 12/12/2018;
```

Btw, you don't need to put a + in front of your variables when you want to set an element's value. And if you instead want to add the value to the current value you use:

```
element.value += 'value to be added'
```